# What does the el #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath} mean?

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to use Exadel Fiji for rendering Pie graphs.

Can someone tell me what does the el `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` mean ?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestContextPath%28%29

Comment: @balusC i need something that translates to a layman

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns you path to your project in *webapps* directory.

For instance, if your project name is myProj,that it will return `/myProj`

As I see,it's needed to avoid hardcoding of your web-project name. For instance, you .war file(archive,that contains your project) may be named different ways and you shouldn't know what exactly name it will be extracted under webapps.

Comment: thanks, can you explain what the various parts in the el mean ?