# Templates and styles not applied on reload in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, css, templates, jsf, jsf-2

I have just started using JSF 2.0 and faced a warmly welcomed issue.
I have used Templates and template client and applied CSS(should mention that I'm not a css expert) styles to the template file. when I run the app everything is fine but when the page is submitted or reloaded or navigated to another page pressing any link or button on the page no style is applied, and just plain HTML is presented.
how can I overcome this problem?

Template File:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>
            <ui:insert name="title">Facelets Template</ui:insert>
        </title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="top" class="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="left">
            <ui:insert name="left">left</ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="left_content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>

        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Client Template:

```
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <body>
        <ui:composition template="./../templates/TutorialsStructure.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">
                Start
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="top">
                <h:graphicImage value="Image/butterfly.gif" style="alignment-adjust: central"/>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="left">
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <div>
                                <h:outputLabel id="outputlabel_userName"     for="inputText_userName" >
                                    <h:outputText id="output_userName" value="UserName:     "/>
                                </h:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h:inputText size="35" id="inputText_userName" value="#    {inputOutputBean.userName}"/>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div>
                                <h:outputLabel id="outputlabel_password"     for="inputsecret_password">
                                    <h:outputText id="output_password" value="Password:     "/>
                                </h:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h:inputSecret id="inputsecret-password" 
                                               value="#{inputOutputBean.password}"
                                               required="true"
                                               requiredMessage="This Field is     obligatory."
                                               size="35">
                                </h:inputSecret>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <div id="submitBtn">
                            <h:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitBtn"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="results_output" styleClass="results">
                        <div>
                            <h:outputLabel id="label_userName"     styleClass="userNameResult" for="userNameResult"
                                           value="User Name: "
                                           style="height: 500px; padding: 2em 2em 2em     2em"/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{inputOutputBean.userName}"     id="userNameResult" >UserName Value:</h:outputText>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h:outputLabel id="outputlabel_password_res"
                                           value="Password Value: "     for="output_password_res"
                                           style="height: 500px; padding: 2em 2em 2em     2em"/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{inputOutputBean.password}"     id="output_password_res"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #036fab;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c2dfef;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ece3a5;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #ece3a5;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

.center_content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;    
}

.left_content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 5px;
}
.right_content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 170px 0px 170px;
}

#top a:link, #top a:visited {
    color: white;
    font-weight : bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top a:link:hover, #top a:visited:hover  {
    color: black;
    font-weight : bold;
    text-decoration : underline;
}


#content{

}

#testID{
    background-color: #111111;
    float: right;
    padding: 10em 10em 10em 10em;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your code which reproduces your problem

Comment: Thank you, Here is the code. I just omitted some xml tags above the documents, here.

Comment: And I should mention that some extra spaces are appeared here and do not exist within the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the links of your `css/images/templates` from `relative` path to `absolute` path.

For example: 
from:

```
<link href="resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to:

```
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` will be replaced to your root directory.

#### See also:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)
- [What does the el #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668175/what-does-the-el-facescontext-externalcontext-requestcontextpath-mean)

Comment: I want to know some about the reason. can you give some more info or a link as a reference?

Comment: @ali honarmand - I add a link to my answer that can help you understand.

Comment: This clumsy approach can be done even less clumsy with `#{request.contextPath}`.

Answer (score 5):

You should not be using `<link>`, but you should be using `<h:outputStylesheet>`. Its `name` attribute takes a path relative to the `/resources` folder and you never need to worry about the context path.

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/cssLayout.css" />
```

Comment: According to this answer, what he should do with  <ui:composition template="./../templates/TutorialsStructure.xhtml"> ?